# How to auto refresh documentation based on an API specification in Postman

Tags: postman

I'm trying to setup a Documentation for my API specification in Postman. My problem right now is that if I modify something on the Open API screen, my documentation does not get updated.

Right now the only way to update it is to delete it and create it again. Any idea how to auto refresh it without doing that? (if it's possible)

I have added this screenshot to help understand what exactly I am using:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to delete the collection every time, you can update previously generated API elements (such as Documentation, Tests etc) through the UI:

- Open the Documentation tab
- Click Validate against Definition at the top-right
- Click Issues Found and access the Issue summary
- Select the changes and Apply

The documentation for that can be found here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/validating-elements-against-schema/#updating-api-elements

And here's a video showing you how to do it: https://youtu.be/BUZiRtGRHj0?t=340

At the moment it is not possible to trigger an update automatically whenever the schema is changed, but you could use the Postman API to pull changes on a regular basis using the `Sync relation with schema` endpoint:
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/documentation/12959542-c8142d51-e97c-46b6-bd77-52bb66712c9a